# Java to MathML Content Type Conversion

Tags: java, mathml

I am looking for a **Java Library** that I can create a very simple MathML in **semantic tags** (preferably a String) in my Java Application, with given set of values. i.e. I need to convert a simple java mathematical equation(e.g. x^2/4) to a MathML semantic tag String.

Any suggestions?